How to efficiently make ASCII art in terminal with Haskell?
This is not a duplicate of Output ascii animation from Haskell?, as that post was, in spite of the title, about how to ensure a minimal pause between frames; regarding the actual drawing, the OP considers

straightforward using putStrLn together with clearScreen from the ansi-terminal package, found via this answer.

What I'm wandering is: do I really have to clearScreen and re-putStrLn every line in the terminal, even if, say, only a handful of characters in the whole terminal change?
Think about implementing snake in a terminal, where most of the time each frame would differ from the previous one by two characters. I think it would be much more efficitent to just update individual characters at the desired positions on the screen, rather than re-render the whole terminal.
What options do I have in Haskell?

No, I'm not looking for ncurses. I'm just curious to know how I can do animations in a terminal, by clearing the screen once, and then just setting/clearing individual screen positions.

You might not be looking for ncurses, but it's looking for you. It abstracts over generating proper escape sequences for your particular terminal emulator to do this sort of thing. You can stick to solely ANSI escape sequences and probably do what you're asking about sufficiently well. But as you get into weirder situations, that's what the abstraction layer is there for.

@Carl, yes, I do understand what you say. For now I just want to experiment (precisely with snake), so I'm curious to see how hard doing the printing myself wiht ANSI is. Later, I can experiment by using ncurses for an alternative. Incidentally, would you say that ncurses, under the hood still does what David Fletcher's answer suggests to do via ANSI? I mean, does ncurses too use the approach of "move the cursor and write"?

Yes, that's what ncurses does. What else could it do? It's not magic, and the only thing it has to interact with is the same terminal you do. So it sends control codes to the terminal. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558348/how-do-ncurses-et-al-work for more details.

@amalloy, What else coudl it do? Well, how do I know? If I only have to change 10 characters on the screen, I'd use individual setCursorPosition and putStr, but maybe ncurses uses some special API of the terminal to update multiple locations "at the same time"? I actually don't know, so I've asked the question.

You overwrite characters in the terminal by moving the cursor to the position you want then writing the character.
The ansi-terminal package has functions like setCursorPosition for this.
Alternatively you can look up the codes and write them yourself.  For example this will write 'x' at 5, 5.
putStr "\ESC[5;5Hx"


When you're using a sequence of putStr commands, you might need to finish by flushing stdout before the changes actually make it to the terminal. This is a case where that's probably important to make note of.
